# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'module'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, sequence

Beginner level

In this code `speed` is keyboard input, `distance` has start, mid and end value and time is varying, so I had written the code that use `distance = speed * time` formula but it is not working.

Why do I get this error and what could be the possible solution?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #input object

# frames iterator
i = 0;

# To capture number of frames
no_of_frames = 0

# coordinates to print time on x and y location
x = 30
y = 30

# take speed as input from keyboard
speed = input()

#total distance
start_distance = 0
total_distance = 75
mid_distance = int(total_distance / 2)

# video start time
start_time = time.time()

# start capturing frames
while(cap.isOpened()):    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        distance = speed * time         
        # capture frame
        #if t == start_distance or t == mid_distance or t == total_distance:
        if distance == start_distance or distance == mid_distance or distance == total_distance:

            # calculate time
            hours, rem = divmod(time.time() - start_time, 3600)
            minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)

            # set elapsed time
            elapsed_time = "{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds)

            # print elapsed time on frame
            cv2.putText(frame,str(elapsed_time), (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, 255)

            # capture frame
            cv2.imwrite('output_frame_'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
            no_of_frames = no_of_frames + 1
            #print(t)

        i=i+1
        if no_of_frames >=3: 
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        else:
            break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
#out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in () 32 33
>   cv2.imshow('frame',frame) ---> 34 distance = speed * time 35 if
>   distance == start_distance or distance == mid_distance or distance ==
>   total_distance: 36 TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of
>   type 'module'

Comment: Please show the error you are getting

Comment: In `speed * time`  `time` variable is not defined and `time` is a module you imported by `import time` hence the error.

Comment: @Chritopher Bottonms                                                                                                         TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e3c327c7c8e5> in <module>()
     32 
     33         cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
---> 34         distance = speed * time
     35         if distance == start_distance or distance == mid_distance or distance == total_distance:
     36 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'module'

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are multiplying `time` and it is the name of the `Time` module, you should use one of the time methods and use it to multiply. Maybe `start_time`, but I don't know the exact purpose of this variable.

Also you need to cast the `speed` to int in order to use it in a multiplication. I assume you want to get an int

**From documentation**

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

```
#Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

And then in your loop:

```
out.write(frame)
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: i have I have replaced time.time() and I have also casted speed to int but now  it just take video. it's not capturing image

Comment: what error does it give? What is the desired output, which output do you have?

Comment: it is just playing video and no error is mentioned and it is not capturing image as well

Answer (score 0):

Since `time` is a package and not a variable, you need to create a variable to hold the current time:

```
current_time = time.time()
distance     = speed * current_time
```

Or you can just get the current time thus:

```
distance     = speed * time.time()
```

Don't get me wrong. I like Python, but this is one example of why languages like Perl and PHP uses sigils like `$` or `@` to denote variables. In these languages, a variable named `time` holding a single value would be written `$time`, while a function (or module) with the same name would be written `time`. Thus it would be harder to confuse the two.